# Jq: How to ignore whitespaces in keys & values

Tags: bash, shell, jq

When making query using Jq Play for the provided json the output looks as expected [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AlDW68LxCgc). But when I try the same query in shell Script & iterate the object I see new row got added because of whitespace between sentence.

Query:

```
query=$(cat $basename/test.json | jq -r '.DesignCode | to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)"')

for i in $query

do
    printf "$i"
done
```

used in the shell script

Output ScreenShot

[image]

What is the correct way to write the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: You can use the same logic for a function and for a file : `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(jq -r '....' input.json)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the output of your command but, in my experience, shell is a bit confusing when it comes to creating arrays from strings.

A useful workaround I use a lot is forcing shell to recognize the output as an array by compound assignment:

```bash
query=( $(cat $basename/test.json | jq -r '.DesignCode | to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)"') )

for i in $query

do
    printf "$i \n"
done
```